# how to leave table rows opened on react table?

Tags: reactjs, show-hide, use-state, react-table, reactstrap

I put a button for SHOW & HIDE on description part since length of description will be pretty long.
I want to leave these buttons working individually and also leave these buttons opened unless I click it again.

The problem is if I click first one and click second one, then it doesn't open second one but close first one.

Here's my code and I know I should work on `isoPen`, `currentReport` and `key`.
I just have no idea how to work it out.

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const [currentReport, setCurrentReport] = useState(0);
```

```
<Table style={{ marginTop: "30px" }}>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="name">name</th>
            <th class="description">description</th>
            <th class="date">date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {data&&
            data.map((value,key)=>
            (
                <tr key={key}>
                    <td class="name">{value.name}</td>
                    <td >
                        <Button color="primary" onClick={() => {
                            setIsOpen(!isOpen);
                            setCurrentReport(key);
                            console.log(currentReport);
                        }}>Show/Hide</Button>
                            <Collapse isOpen={isOpen&&(currentReport===key)}>
                                <Card>
                                    ...
                                </Card>
                                <div style={{marginTop:'5px', marginLeft:'2px', textAlign:'right'}}>
                                    <Button color='info' onClick={()=>{
                                        setEditOn(!editOn);
                                        setCurrentReport(key);
                                    }}>Update</Button>
                                        <Modal isOpen={editOn&&(currentReport===key)} toggle={toggle}>
                                            ...
                                        </Modal>
                                    <Button color='danger' onClick={()=>{
                                        ...
                                    }}>Delete</Button>
                                </div>
                            </Collapse>
                    </td>
                    <td class="date" style={{ fontSize:'smaller' }}>{value.year}/ <br/>{value.month}/ {value.date}</td>
                </tr>
            ))}
    </tbody>
</Table>
```

Also since I put `0` in `useState()` of `const [currentReport, setCurrentReport]` though I click second or third one at the first time, `console.log(currentReport)` shows `0` at the first time. Obviously...
What value should I put in `useState()` of `const [currentReport, setCurrentReport]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here's my code and I know I should work on isoPen, currentReport and key. I just have no idea how to work it out.

Your intuition is correct. You have to change `isOpen` flag into a list of flags where index in this list would correspond with index in your `data` which is mapped to components. Just don't forget to initialize it. `currentReport` will have nothing to do with show&hide mechanic.
Each time you use `isOpen` you should now use `isOpen[key]` instead:

```
<Collapse isOpen={isOpen&&(currentReport===key)}>
```

intoto

```
<Collapse isOpen={isOpen[key] && (currentReport===key)}>
```

Also you need to change button's behaviour: it needs to copy the `isOpen` array, change the value under the index and then set the state to the new value (you can't just change the value in the array bacause react won't see this modified array as a new value- the reference must change)

```
<Button color="primary" onClick={() => {
    let newIsOpen = [...isOpen];      //copy array
    newIsOpen[key] = !newIsOpen[key]; //toggle flag
    setIsOpen(newIsOpen);             //set new state
    setCurrentReport(key);
    console.log(currentReport);
 }}>Show/Hide</Button>
```

I'm uncertain about what `currentReport` is for, but I guess it points out which report is about to be modified somehow (if that's the case I would recommend adding another button for it), so for the first time (before any report is pointed by user) you should simply put there  `null` or even `undefined` value.

```
const [currentReport, setCurrentReport] = useState(undefined);
```

Comment: Thank u sooo mcuh for such a detailed answer!! 
But since <isOpen> is not iterable, your solution gave me an "not iterable" ERROR thing. But still I get ur point which is handling it individually by giving index number to an array will work. 
I guess I should figure out how to handle that opening table row thing individually...

Comment: @Flash-KIM142, at which line do you get the 'not iterable' error? I guess it's because you did not change `useState`; if this is the case at the first your `isOpen` is `true` instead of an array which would definitely cause that kind of error when `let newIsOpen = [...isOpen];      //copy array` is executed

Comment: I just changed my code from ```const [isOpen, setItOpen] = useState(false);``` to ```... = useState([false]);```. It worked sort of.. but still has few bugs. On the bright side, I don't get that NOT ITERABLE ERROR thing anymore. I think from here, I have to do it on my own... From your answer I got enough clues how to fix this! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: nope.... I get that error again...and the error comes from ```let newIsOpen = [...isOpen];``` but still I think I got clues where to go. Thanks again...

Comment: @Flash-KIM142, please consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: Oh I totally forgot about that just thinking about solving my error. sorry about that and thanks :)